# custom keyboard for app on android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'd like to have my own custom keyboard on android
What I don't want is an inputService (of which I can find plenty of documentation)
I want to have a keyboard in my application and only in my application, but can't seem to find any good documentation or tutorial on how to do it.

I've found some classes extending View and drawing a keyboard, but then how do I disable the android keyboard? Do I need to extend Keyboard? KeyboardView? ...?

A lot of questions and hopefully soon a couple of answers!

Oh, the solution should be for android 2.1 and up

Comment: unfortunately it is a business requirement that I put in the keyboard, so I'm aware that some users won't like it